# <input type="file" /> onchange property when clicking cancel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have

`<input type="file" id="file" onchange="filename();" /> <div id='filename'></div>`

The function goes something like this

```
function filename() {
var input = document.getElementById("file");
if (filename == null) {
   document.getElementById("filename").innerHTML = "";
   return false;
}

var lastIndex = filename.lastIndexOf("\\");
if (lastIndex >= 0) {
   filename = filename.substring(lastIndex + 1);
}
document.getElementById("filename").innerHTML = "The filename is: "+filename+".";
}
```

My code is similar to the above, and works fine, but when clicking on choose file, then choosing a file, the filename is shown. After that, if I click choose file, then hit cancel. Now the file is not loaded anymore, but the text that says the filename is still there. Is there a code I can use that will automatically listen to the file field all the time, and when the file value is empty it will change the filename?

I want to do this using JavaScript or jQuery.

**EDIT**

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    $("#file").change(function() {
         alert('changed');
    });
});
```

This will detect new images selected and when the file selection window is exited (when pressing cancel) the file's name attr. is changed to "", which is what I wanted.

Comment: i think after you hit cancel, the filename is still the previous value, not changed...so

Comment: maybe it is changed to "", not null. your code is waiting for null.

Comment: tried both. neither work.

Comment: the problem is that the onchange method is cancelled when the user pressed cancel. It is only waiting for an image to be selected.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure about what you mean by 'loaded' or 'the text'. Does loaded mean: shown in the input box? And does the text mean: the text in the filename div?

The text in the filename div will only change if the input box is changed. Hitting cancel won't change the input box.

If after hitting cancel, the file in the input box disappears, then that's supposed to happen.

Also: you're comparing the function filename to null.
you might want to use input.value

Comment: I meant that when a file is chosen, the filename field updates with the name. But when hitting cancel, it doesn't erase the contents of the filename field, because the onchange field doesn't update with the cancel event.

I edited the question, I found a solution.